# Is there any truth to the claim that pregnancy is somehow a health risk to women?

Tags: obstetrics, risks

I've heard people say that pregnancy is somehow dangerous for a woman.

I know that you can get high blood pressure, and gestational diabetes but that's usually among obese women. The conditions are also temporary.

I also know that during childbirth there can be complications.

How exactly is being pregnant bad for your health? It's a natural and normal biological process.

Let's focus on recent stats and healthy women between ages 20-35 who are not obese and don't have any pre-existing medical conditions.

Comment: Just because something is natural and normal doesn't make it healthy. Fever is natural and normal, allergies are natural and normal and they're both potentially lethal (but rarely)

Comment: Look at ages on old tombstones in the US , many young women and some newborns will be listed. Much lower risk in the US today ,but clearly higher risk than not having a baby.

Comment: @blacksmith37 And it is still much higher risk in the US than in other similarly developed countries.

Comment: Despite having access to excellent medical care, a young woman in my community recently developed a strep infection following childbirth. It evolved into sepsis and she died. Infections are just one of several potentially lethal risks of pregnancy.

Comment: Can you use non-US stats and some scientific studies done that the state of being pregnant is somehow detrimental to your health?

Comment: Life is also a risk for health. If you live, you have a higher risk to get a disease than if you don't.

Comment: @Jan `If you live, you have a higher risk to get a disease than if you don't.` -- Do you have citations to support that claim? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

In the U.S., [14 in every 100 000 pregnancies are fatal for the mother](https://www.unfpa.org/maternal-health). While this may not seem much, consider the following graphic:

[image]

<sup>In picture B and D the blue bars indicate deaths due to pregnancies. While those numbers have decreased since 1990, in 2010 they still accounted for a large proportion of deaths of women in that age group.</sup>

---

A selection of problems that can occur during a pregnancy (not ranked in any way)

- Infections (due to open wounds during labor and birth)
- Thrombosis (due to immovability)
- Anemia (low count of red blood cells)
- Heart failures (due to the strain put on the heart)

During a pregnancy, the woman's body supplies both the foetus and the mother with oxygen, blood and food. This puts a lot of strain on the organism. While humans are built so that they can handle it, it does increase the risks of the above and many more problems, so that pregnancy indeed is a risk factor.

Comment: It's worth noting, however, that pregnancies (especially below 30 years of age) and breastfeeding reduce the long-term risk of e.g. breast and ovarian cancer (this probably doesn't have an impact on life expectancy, though)

Comment: Another point which can alter the statistics is that women are having babies at older ages than in the past due to wanting to have a career first.

Comment: @ChrisRogers yes that's true. Also obesity, pre-existing conditions, etc. play a role. But for a healthy woman between ages 20 and 35 I'm seeing a very low chance that pregnancy could impact her health too much.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Narusan addresses the fundamental aspects, these additions are historically recent modulators. How about writing another A that addresses these changes (or international/regional differences)?

Comment: @user1261710 Well, it makes up for approximately 10% of deaths of women the age 20-40. This includes the developing nations, but as it is more „natural“ there (and lower obesity risk factors etc.), you‘d expect the number to be less. Dunno what‘s a „little impact“ to you

Comment: I guess my motive for asking this question is kind of political. My adversaries are always trying to say that pregnancy is an awful thing for women and it harms their health so certain hormonal substances are needed for a woman's wellbeing. I'm trying to compare the negative health risks of hormonal contraceptives vs pregnancy but there are other methods of contraceptives.

Comment: @user1261710 That‘s sort of an XY-Problem. **In normal patients, neither (hormonal and other) contraceptives are discouraged, nor a pregnancy**. The health risks of both are low (very low for contraceptives). Using contraceptives is rather to prevent pregnancy than to prevent serious health effects, and so the argument boils down to the degree of control and choice humans should have about birth and contraception. I have never seen or read an argument made because of health reasons.

Comment: @Narusan the health risks for oral contraceptives are somewhat low (in my opinion increased risk of breast cancer, depression, sexual dysfunction are not insignificant) but the side effects can be horrendous. Are side effects not considered to be health risks? I've seen some arguments made in the name of women's health (no doubt politically motivated) saying that pregnancy is significantly more dangerous than oral contraceptives.

Comment: @user1261710 Well, IMHO they are.

Comment: @CareyGregory it does not account for the deaths of 10% of all women. And there have been many deaths from the use of oral contraceptives. 8 deaths in 100,000 live births is not 10% of all women. I think you are getting political now.

Comment: @user1261710 a) just look at the graph. The blue part is approximately 10% (give or take 2%), and it denotes death caused by maternal problems. Obviously we are only taking into account women who can conceive, so there’s no point to look at values of pre-teen  or post-menopause women. I have heard and read about maternal deaths, but I have yet to come across any death caused by contraceptives. [Studies found that those actually prolong life](https://www.medpagetoday.com/obgyn/generalobgyn/18971). For further discussion, please visit the [chat]

Comment: @user1261710 I assure you I have no political motivations here.